# Pipeline date variable value changed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a variable in Azure DevOps pipeline:

```
TIMESTAMP: "2016-01-16T00:00:00"
```

I use this variable in my template to substitute variable in this template, but during pipeline execution, pipeline always change format this value to: `01/16/2016 00:00:00`.

Is it possible to keep first format? I need variable in exactly this form: `2016-01-16T00:00:00`.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your pipeline or the YAML?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the variable with single quotes:

```
TIMESTAMP: "'2016-01-16T00:00:00'"
```

Result:

[image]